# Can't load default Firefox profile into selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the latest Firefox selenium geckodriver - and the code below fails to load my default firefox profile. It loads the url, but not using the firefox profile I want (it uses the standard selenium firefox profile)

I have checked the profile root address and it is correct.

Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options=Options()

ppath = '/home/james/.mozilla/firefox/7fhp9ar4.default-release-1607447335464'
options.set_preference('profile', ppath)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https:google.com")
```